# Spaces not appearing in variable

Tags: bash, shell

Here is my code:

```
var="       Hello         "/n"      There       "
echo -e "$var"
```

But I get

```
Hello        n         There
```

as my output, How do I make the output say

```
       Hello        
       There
```

instead?

Answer (score 3):

The first issue is your newline's slash is pointing the wrong way.  It should be "\n" to produce a newline.  You also have a lot of extra quotes that are breaking up your string.  There is no reason to stop and restart your string before/after your newline.

```
 var="   Hello\n   There"
 echo -e "$var"
```

... will produce what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var="\tHello\n\tThere"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use printf and arrays to separate the content from the formatting

```
var=(Hello There)
printf '\t%s\t\n' "${var[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [ANSI C quoted string](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings):

```
echo $'       Hello         /n      There       '
```

This way you don't even need `-e` flag :)